# Suppressing printout of specific C++ object properties in gdb?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

Let's say we have the following file, `test.cpp`, compiled with `g++ --std=c++11 -g test.cpp -o test.exe`:

```cpp
// test.cpp
// g++ --std=c++11 -g test.cpp -o test.exe
// gdb -ex "b test.cpp:37" -ex "r" -ex "p obj1" -ex "p obj2" --args test.exe
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Tester {
public:
  std::string id = "";
  std::vector<int> important;
  std::vector<int> unimportant;
};

int main()
{
  Tester obj1;
  Tester obj2;

  obj1.id = "OBJ1";
  obj1.important.push_back(1);
  obj1.important.push_back(2);
  obj1.important.push_back(3);
  obj1.important.push_back(4);
  for (int i=0; i<25; i++) {
    obj1.unimportant.push_back(-10000000);
  }

  obj2.id = "OBJ2";
  obj2.important.push_back(5);
  obj2.important.push_back(6);
  obj2.important.push_back(7);
  obj2.important.push_back(8);
  for (int i=0; i<25; i++) {
    obj2.unimportant.push_back(-10020000);
  }

  std::cout << "Before exit (for breakpoint): " << obj1.important.size() << ", " << obj2.important.size() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

If this program is run in `gdb`, through the command line given above, I get this:

```
$ gdb -ex "b test.cpp:37" -ex "r" -ex "p obj1" -ex "p obj2" --args test.exe 
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1
...
Starting program: /tmp/test.exe 

Breakpoint 1, main () at test.cpp:37
37    std::cout << "Before exit (for breakpoint): " << obj1.important.size() << ", " << obj2.important.size() << std::endl;
$1 = {id = "OBJ1", important = std::vector of length 4, capacity 4 = {1, 2, 3, 4}, 
  unimportant = std::vector of length 25, capacity 32 = {-10000000, -10000000, -10000000, -10000000, -10000000, -10000000, 
    -10000000, -10000000, -10000000, -10000000, -10000000, -10000000, -10000000, -10000000, -10000000, -10000000, -10000000, 
    -10000000, -10000000, -10000000, -10000000, -10000000, -10000000, -10000000, -10000000}}
$2 = {id = "OBJ2", important = std::vector of length 4, capacity 4 = {5, 6, 7, 8}, 
  unimportant = std::vector of length 25, capacity 32 = {-10020000, -10020000, -10020000, -10020000, -10020000, -10020000, 
    -10020000, -10020000, -10020000, -10020000, -10020000, -10020000, -10020000, -10020000, -10020000, -10020000, -10020000, 
    -10020000, -10020000, -10020000, -10020000, -10020000, -10020000, -10020000, -10020000}}
```

In this case, I don't really care about the vector property `unimportant` above, and since it has many elements, its printout makes reading much more difficult than it should be. However, I'm interested in all other properties of the object, so `p`rinting them individually might take me quite a bit of work to simply enumerate them in a `gdb` command script (if the object has many properties).

So, is there a way to suppress the printout in `gdb` of only a single property (in this case, `.unimportant`) of an object, or even better of a class? Instead of `unimportant = std::vector of length 25, capacity 32 = {...}`, I'd be happy with something like `unimportant = std::vector of length 25, capacity 32 = { __noprint__ }` in the printout...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way to suppress the printout in gdb of only a single property

Without defining a custom pretty-printer: no.

You can make `print` command do anything you want by defining a custom pretty printer for your class. Documentation [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Writing-a-Pretty_002dPrinter.html).

Comment: Thanks for that, @EmployedRussian - good to have this confirmed; cheers!